# Display selected menu Item has to display in the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using kendo UI menu.
I have defined like

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
     dataSource: [
             { text: "parent",
                 items: [
                                { text: "child1" },
                                { text: "child2" },
                                { text: "child3" },
                                { text: "child4" }
                            ]
               }     
             ],
      select:function(e){
            $(e.item).children(".k-link").text();
       }
   });
```

Initially the menu displays the text as "parent".
What I want is, in the select event, when I click on any other item, the selected item text has to display in the top menu. Tell me how to change the text in kendo menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite a `menu` uses a DataSource for building the initial content, then it is no longer used and any operation in the DataSource is not directly reflected in the Menu. Which means that you have to manipulate DOM objects for replacing the text.

```
// Get selected text
var text = $(e.item).text();
// Get the first parent (in case you have multiple menu levels) 
var topParent = $(e.item).parents("li").last();
// And now go to the node that contains the text
var textParent = $("> span.k-link",  topParent);
// Go to the content (text) and replace it with child text
textParent.contents().first()[0].textContent = text;
```

See it in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/kfcdF/